# jQuery not displaying on JSP page when called from servlet

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets

Hi I'm fairly new to jQuery and am trying to add a simple jQuery tab component to an existing jsp page which is called from a servlet.
If I access the page directly, the jQuery components appear but when the page is called from the servlet the page displays but the jQuery effects dont work. It appears jQuery never gets called.

Sample code below:

I am just getting the following instead of the tabs effect

```
*Tabs

    * First
    * Second
    * Third

This is tab one
This is tab two.
This is tab three*
```

Can anybody help, I have searched the web for days looking for answer but havent had any luck. Any help would be very much appreciated

I have added an popup which appears when page called directly from browser but doesnt get called when page called from servlet

### TestServlet

```
public class SBServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public SBServlet()
    {
        super();
    }  


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {

        // redirecting to test.jsp
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/JSP/test.jsp").forward(request,response);        

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
          doPost(request, response);    
    }


}
```

### test.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link type="text/css" href="../css/hot-sneaks/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('jQuery is accessible');
    $("#tabs").tabs();
  });


</script>


<title>Jquery test</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2 class="demoHeaders">Tabs</h2>
  <div id="tabs">

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">First</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-3">Third</a></li>
    </ul>

      <div id="tabs-1">This is tab one</div>
      <div id="tabs-2">This is tab two.</div>
      <div id="tabs-3">This is tab three</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you verify that the jquery is loading when you call it from the servlet?  Could it be that your path to the jquery has changed?

Comment: I dont think jquery is loading. The popup is never getting called which it does if I call the page directly

Comment: What does the URL look like when you call it normally vs when you call it using the servlet?

Comment: Well I'm using tomcat server so its http://localhost:8080/Test/JSP/test.jsp which jQuery displays ok with. From the servlet I'm calling initial jsp file which calls servlet which forwards to test.jsp. THe URL is http://localhost:8080/Test/SBServlet?handler=login

Comment: Ok so when you call the server does the browser URL change on redirect to `localhost:8080/Test/JSP/test.jsp`?  Or does it stay as `localhost:8080/Test/SBServlet?handler=login`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Well I'm using tomcat server so its localhost:8080/Test/JSP/test.jsp which jQuery displays ok with. From the servlet I'm calling initial jsp file which calls servlet which forwards to test.jsp. THe URL is localhost:8080/Test/SBServlet?handler=login

You've declared the script URLs relative to the current request URL.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js"></script>
```

If you have debugged the HTTP traffic with for example [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com), you would have noticed that on the servlet URL the scripts are been loaded from `http://localhost:8080/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js` and `http://localhost:8080/js/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js` which each obviously returns a 404 page not found.

You want to load them from context path `/Test`. You need to fix the script URLs so that they are relative to the domain root instead of the current request URL.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js"></script>
```

This would then end up in the generated HTML as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Test/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Test/js/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js"></script>
```