# Loading a jsp page using JQuery

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets

I have a specific div in my page where I want to load all the subpages (I'm using JQuery for this). Before loading them I need to do some operations in the server, so I call my servlet and after all operations are done I want to load the .jsp page... but I have no idea how.

With responseText being:

```
/SAJ/WebContent/WEB-INF/views/administracion/semestres/semestreIndex.jsp
```

(the route in my project structure where wanted .jsp is stored)

I got it to write responseText in the div:

```
<div id="content" class="testDiv" >
```

using this:

```
function load() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/SAJ/pages/semestre",
        success: function(responseText) {
            $('#content').text(responseText); 
        }
    });
}
```

but I have no idea how to load the whole page. My first idea was to do this:

```
function load() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/SAJ/pages/semestre",
        success: function(responseText) {
            $('#content').load(responseText); 
        }
    });
}
```

But I get a 404 error in Chrome's console:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/SAJ/WebContent/WEB-INF/views/administracion/semestres/semestreIndex.jsp 404 (Not Found)
```

I suppose than I'm using the wrong route? But how can I find which one is the correct one? I'm just following my project structure:

[image: Project structure]

**Servlet code:**

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
    try {
        Action action = ((ActionFactory) getServletContext().getAttribute("actions")).getAction(request);
        String view = action.execute(request, response);
        if(view.equals("index")){
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/" + view + ".jsp").forward(request, response);
        }else{
            response.getWriter().write("/SAJ/WebContent/WEB-INF/" + view + ".jsp");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ServletException("Executing action failed.", e);
    }
}
```

**Action called by the servlet:**

```
public class SemestreListarAction implements Action{

    public String execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{
    request.setAttribute("test", "HELLO WORLD!");
    System.out.println("I'm nice so I did some stuff for you!");

        return "views/administracion/semestres/semestreIndex";
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Redirector</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.saj.controller.Redirector</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Redirector</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Caller:**

```
<a href="#" onclick="load()">Load</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `.html()`?

Comment: Yes, and I got the same result as my first test (using .text()) since my request returns a text with jsp' path not a html page.

Comment: what about `.getScript()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery not displaying on JSP page when called from servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492926/jquery-not-displaying-on-jsp-page-when-called-from-servlet)

Comment: Using $('#content').getScript(responseText);  gives: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getScript'. But why would I use that one, I'm not trying to load a script but a jsp page.

Answer (score 3):

Lets admit you have this div :

```
<div id='result'></div>
```

Try  to use `.load()` like this :

```
function load(jsp_path) {

    $("#result").load(jsp_path);

}
```

Comment: Is that what I'm doing when calling: 
        function(responseText) {
            $('#content').load(responseText); 
        }
since responseText is the jsp_path?

Comment: please post your servlet code as well , and tell me what is the page from where you call ajax

Comment: I posted my servlet code, I'm sure that it's being called properly because I get the test prints in server's console, and also .text() and .html() give the expected outputs. However I have no clue about why .load() doesn't.  

The caller is index.jsp (the other file showed in the screen, which located in the /WEB-INF directory).

Comment: ok , i think problem is your path http://localhost:8080/SAJ/WebContent/WEB-INF/views/administracion/semestres/semestreIndex.jsp , you have 404 error , can you access it from browser ?

Comment: No, I can't. Yet, I don't know which the correct path should be, am not I supposed to follow the project structure?

Comment: Your servlet should return this path , try it : 
views/administracion/semestres/semestreIndex.jsp

Comment: Actually my server returns: "/SAJ/WebContent/WEB-INF/views/administracion/semestres/semestreIndex.jsp" but I tried "/SAJ/views/administracion/semestres/semestreIndex.jsp" without any result

Comment: Noo try this            `response.getWriter().write("views/administracion/semestres/semestreIndex.jsp");`

Comment: I finally gor it to work, using window.location + returning the jsp path as you said. My problem was a missing a "#" in de path.

Comment: cool , take a look of relative path to understand why is this path working

Comment: The complete path is "http://localhost:8080/SAJ/#views/administracion/semestres/semestreIndex.jsp", the # comes from the div where I call the function: <a href="#" onclick="load()">Load</a>.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after finally being able to load something I found out that because how everything is configured the only thing that go load was the index. To correct this I changed my logic.

First I ask for the page using only the Load function:

```
function Load() {
$.ajaxSetup({
    data: { load: '/semestre' }
});

$('#content').load("#/views/administracion/semestres/semestreIndex.jsp"); //jsp's path
}
```

and then change my servlet (so it redirects to the correct path where the jsp resides) and actionFactory to use the parameter load instead of request.getPathInfo()

**Servlet:**

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        Action action = ((ActionFactory) getServletContext().getAttribute("actions")).getAction(request);
        String view = action.execute(request, response);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/" + view + ".jsp").forward(request, response);           
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ServletException("Executing action failed.", e);
    }
}
```

**Action factory:**

```
public Action getAction(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Action action = actions.get(request.getParameter("load"));

    if(action == null)
        return new DefaultAction();
    else
        return action;
}
```

In conlusion, the problem was both in the path and in my logic. There was no need to use $ajax and $load in my case, since $load is a http request by itself so I can do the logic and then load the page with the correct values in the same call. The problem in the path was thanks a missing "#".

I would like to know if there is a way to change the request path so I can erase the "load" parameter, besides that everything work smoothly now.

Answer (score 0):

One key thing here is , make sure your jsp is not in the web-inf directory, move it to the level equal to web-inf or to a directory at the same level as web-inf.